# Do we need to use javascript to create a responsive layout?

Tags: javascript, css

I made the download of several free responsive layout (you can find them simply through google if you're curious) and I see that the layout has at least one or two javascript files.

The question is: javascript is essential to create a responsive layout?

Then, in the reply to this question is "no" and you have also the possibility to link a free responsive layout made only with html and css, well, you will receive a wonderfull BIG thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The whole point of responsive layouts is that it can (and should) be done with CSS3 media queries only.

However, this can often require some clever HTML design, especially if you want to have a slide-in menu (hint: `:active` can be very powerful when combined with `tabindex` to make an otherwise "inert" element respond to click events like a link) and many developers just can't be bothered with that, especially when jQuery is so readily available.

So basically, yes, you can make a responsive layout with CSS only. And if you succeed, congratulations! JavaScript can be used to make things easier, but in general if you think you need it, you probably just need to rethink how you're doing things.

Unfortunately, I have no links to JavaScript-less responsive layouts for you, that's because I'm very DIM - Doin' It Meself!

---

*Edit back* While I appreciate Martijn's demonstration of a use of JavaScript in making images essentially have variable resolution depending on screen size, images can be made responsive simply by using SVG if possible. If this is not an option, consider using a container with a `background-image` - only the image that matches the media query will be loaded :)

Comment: what about browser compatibility? Several css3 properties are not read with some browser (the oldest versions), while media queries? Can i meet problems of compatibility with them?

Comment: Just ignore those. Make sure your normal website looks good there, those types of users aren't gonna resize a lot anyways (unless, offcourse, they are a significant amount of your target)

Comment: @nietTheDark: Hope you dont mind me expanding your answer, felt like it needed a small example to clearify

Comment: @Martijn That's fine. Although personally I'd use SVG for responsive images ;)

Comment: @Martijn This is about JS-less webdesign…

Comment: Additionally, you can use `background-image` instead - when used with media queries, the image is only loaded when needed... hmm... sorry, gonna have to strip your edit out.

Comment: feeela: No it isnt, its about wether it is JS or not :) Just giving an example WHEN JS is practical to use.

Comment: @the svg suggestion: Though I like to, there are 2 reason I didnt: SVG's are bigger in filesize for example sketchy logo's. And IE8 has NO support at all, so that isnt always an option

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes yes, sometimes no.

First understand what is response layout: Responsive Layout is the one that dynamically changes itself. Depending on the Browser's screen size. So that it fits perfectly on every screen type, size, resolution etc. So that the website's layout doesn't break.

You can just use CSS3 media query to change the layout, or else you can use jQuery or some other JavaScript to make this happen.

But remember, JavaScript is not required to make the document Responsive.

#### Sometimes Yes!

Sometimes the developer is better in writing the code using JavaScript, such as jQuery API. So he would find it easy to write the code in jQuery to dynamically handle all the events in the Browser window to make a website Responsive.

I myself would find it pretty easy to write the code in jQuery as compared to CSS. So for that purpose, I would have to add the jQuery source file to the document to render it that way. Otherwise I won't be able to create the responsiveness in the Website or would have to stick to the pure JavaScript

Example would be:

```
if($(window).width() > '1300') {
  $('body').css({
    'height': '100%' /* etc */
  });
}
```

#### Sometimes No!

Some developers are good at CSS (CSS3, and its media Queries too). So they try using CSS3 to render the document and make it responsive.

CSS3 is really much easy than jQuery and it would be helpfull to use it. It would also won't require any of the Script file to be included. You can easily write the code, in the default CSS file. And the changes would be made accordingly.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
  body {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

#### But Remember

If you use plain CSS and then use CSS3 Media Queries to change the layout of the website, you will be able to just detect the screen size and other elements. You won't be able to check for the Browser's properties or the content on the screen etc.

Comment: Your "sometimes yes" argument is invalid. Our job is not supposed to be "easy". I regularly torture myself to make everything maximally efficient.

Answer (score 3):

Both answers are acceptable.
No, if you pretend to work with something like a flash site, which I hardly discourage it.

Yes, because javascript is essential to do that, CSS3/HTML5 are solutions to your case, but, they come with some javascript included functions, that you will not see, so, there is javascript.

Answer (score 2):

**Responsive by Default**

No, you do not need JavaScript for Responsive Webdesign. It is necessary for those cool fly outs and sliding effects.

If you do a website in pure CSS, you might need to take some compromises like a different menu layout or always visible sidebar content. Sliders are a problem.

But consider this:

> If you think about it, responsive layout is not a new thing. Open a simple HTML file in a web browser, and the content automatically adapts to fit the width of that browser. The web is responsive on its own—by default. It's us that's been breaking it all these years by placing content in fixed-width containers.

Andy Hume in "Responsive by Default",
http://blog.andyhume.net/responsive-by-default/

Answer (score 1):

Media queries allows you, to do responsive pages with css only. But you should remember about jquery function '.resize()' when user change horizontal layout to vertical on phone or tablet.

Comment: Nope, just use `orientation:portrait/landscape`